# "this target might include its own product" for nib in dependency

Tags: cocoapods

I created a podspec file that includes the dependencies

```
s.dependency 'CountryPickerSwift', '~> 1.4'
s.dependency 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 2.1.0'
```

When I try to build I get these errors:

> ```
> Unable to run command 'StripNIB CountryView.nib' - this target might include its own product.
> Unable to run command 'StripNIB CountryViewiphone.nib' - this target might include its own product.
> Unable to run command 'StripNIB CountryViewipad.nib' - this target might include its own product.
> ```

As pointed out by others, the solution is to add the nib to the s.resource section of the podspecs,
but it turns out that those nibs are not part of my code, they are part of a dependency (CountryPickerSwift). What should be done in this case?

Pod version: 1.5.0
Swift: 4
OSX: Sierra 10.12.6